# How to get Last Updated date for a document from confluence page through api?

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to get Last Updated date from confluence for a document by using the api but was not able to get it. Can someone point me in the right direction? One solution recommended was to use requests library along with Beautiful Soup and parse the html but I am looking to get this done via an api but so far did not have much success.

I am using this:
https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html
and this:
https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/atlassian/confluence.py

I saw the following in the first link i provided:

#Compare content and check is already updated or not

```
confluence.is_page_content_is_already_updated(page_id, body)
```

But what I want is to grab the date a document was last updated. This date is present in our confluence docs and the title is “Last Updated” . This last updated date is present in front of every document.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this has not been answered, so here's my take after some research:

```
goOn = True
pages = list()
startAt = 0
while(goOn):
    batch = confluence.get_all_pages_from_space('<ConfluenceSpaceName>', start=startAt, limit=100, status=None, expand='title,history.lastUpdated')
    pages.extend(batch)
    startAt = len(pages)
    if (len(batch) == 0):
        goOn = False

for p in pages:
    if (debug): print('Page {}; updated: {}'.format(p['title'], p['history']['lastUpdated']['when']))
```

Thanks, Kirill